# Как заменить ссылку в меню плагина на Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, menu, фильтры

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с установленным плагином [idcommerce](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/ignitiondeck/) в котором есть функция вывода верхнего меню.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'idc_check_customizer');

function idc_check_customizer() {
  add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'idc_update_menus', 10, 2);
}

function idc_update_menus($nav, $args) {
  global $permalink_structure;
  if (empty($permalink_structure)) {
    $prefix = '&';
  }
  else {
    $prefix = '?';
  }
  $durl = md_get_durl();
  $location = $args->theme_location;
  $option = get_option('idc_menu_'.$location);
  if ($option) {
    do_action('idc_menu_before');
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
      $idc_menu = '<li class="createaccount buttonpadding"><a href="'.$durl.'">'.__('My Account', 'memberdeck').'</a></li>';
      $idc_menu .= '<li class="login right"><a href="'.wp_logout_url( home_url() ).'">'.__('Logout', 'memberdeck').'</a></li>';
    }
    else {
      $idc_menu = '<li class="createaccount buttonpadding"><a href="'.$durl.$prefix.'action=register">'.__('Create Account', 'memberdeck').'</a></li>';
      $idc_menu .= '<li class="login right"><a href="'.$durl.'">'.__('Login', 'memberdeck').'</a></li>';
    }
    do_action('idc_menu_after');
    $nav .= apply_filters('idc_menu', $idc_menu);
  }
  return $nav;
}
```

Мне нужно переопределить вывод всего лишь одной ссылки **logina,**

```
$idc_menu .= '<li class="login right"><a href="'.$durl.'">'.__('Login', 'memberdeck').'</a></li>';
```

заменить вместо сформированной в переменной ссылки на информационную панель **$durl=/dashboard** на страницу логина **/login** не заменяя вывод в ядре самого плагина.

В **functions.php** если удаляю экшн

```
remove_action('after_setup_theme', 'idc_check_customizer');
```

и дублирую точно такой же фильтр, но уже с ссылкой на **/login**, то в меню он выводится, но тем самым исчезает левая часть меню, которая принадлежит тому же nav. Как все сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо добавить свой фильтр `wp_nav_menu_items` с более высоким приоритетом (20), чтобы он выполнился позднее:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_idc_update_menus', 20, 2 );

function my_idc_update_menus( $nav, $args ) {
    $durl     = md_get_durl();
    $location = $args->theme_location;
    $option   = get_option( 'idc_menu_' . $location );
    if ( $option ) {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $search  = '<li class="login right"><a href="' . $durl . '">' . __( 'Login', 'memberdeck' ) . '</a></li>';
            $replace = '<li class="login right"><a href="/login">' . __( 'Login', 'memberdeck' ) . '</a></li>';
            $nav     = str_replace( $search, $replace, $nav );
        }
    }

    return $nav;
}
```

Поместите этот код в functions.php.